# If $e^{2\pi i}=1$ then is $2\pi i=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, exponential-function, pi

So with Euler identity I used $2 \pi(\tau)$ instead and got $e^{2\pi i} = 1$, and took natural logarithm $2\pi i= 0$? But is see online the answer is $6.28....i$.

Comment: The   logarithm of a complex number is not unique, but has an infinite number of values separated by $ \ 2 \pi \ i \ $ .  So zero is just _one_ possible value.  You can see this in what you wrote:  $ \ e^0 \ $ also equals 1 , and so does $ \ e^{4 \pi i } \ ,  \ e^{-2 \pi i } \ $ , etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function

Comment: Interesting I'll have a read thanks

Comment: $(-1)^2 = 1^2$ so $-1 = 1$? Obviously not. Similarly, what you wrote isn't true also, it just means when you allow for complex number solutions, $e^x=1$ has solutions other than $x=0$.

Comment: Well, in fact, the complex exponential function is a group homomorphism from the additive group of complex numbers to the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers with kernel $2\pi{i}\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $e^x=e^y$ iff $x-y \in 2\pi{i}\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

In $(0,\infty)$, every number has one and only one real logarithm. So, in $(0,\infty)$, it makes sense to assert that $e^x=y\iff x=\log y$.

However, every complex numbers has infinitely many logarithms. In particular *every* number of the form $2k\pi i$ (with $k\in\mathbb Z$) is **a** logarithm of $1$. So, your approach does not work here.

Another way of seeing this is: in $\mathbb R$, the exponential function is injective, but not in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 2):

The exponential function $f(x)=e^x$ is a group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{C},+)$ to $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$. And yes, this group homomorphism is not injective, for $f(2\pi{i})=f(0)=1$. In fact, $\operatorname{Ker}(f)=2\pi{i}\mathbb{Z}$.