# Why is $\ln(1) \neq \ln(e^{2i\pi})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know:
$$\ln{1} = 0$$
$$e^{2i\pi} = 1$$
So then why is the following not true:
$$\ln(1)=0$$
$$\ln(e^{2i\pi})=0$$
$$2i\pi=0$$
$$i=0$$

Comment: Welcome to branches.

Comment: Because in Complex Analysis, unlike Real Analysis, given complex numbers $~z_1, z_2,~$ the premise that $~e^{z_1} = e^{z_2}~$ does **not** imply that $~z_1 = z_2.$  More specifically, if $~r_1, ~r_2 \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ and $~\theta_1, ~\theta_2 \in \Bbb{R},~$ then you have that $$r_1e^{i\theta_1} = r_2e^{i\theta_2} \implies [ ~(r_1 = r_2) \wedge (\theta_1 \equiv \theta_2 ~\text{mod} ~2\pi) ~].$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $e^{2\pi i}=1$ then is $2\pi i=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665046/if-e2-pi-i-1-then-is-2-pi-i-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go to complex numbers to find a paradox like this.
\begin{align}
 \arccos( 1) &= 0. \\
 \cos(2\pi) &= 1. \\
 \arccos(\cos(2\pi)) &= 0. \\
 2\pi &\stackrel?= 0. 
\end{align}

The paradox occurs because $\cos(x)$ takes the same value for many different input values $x$, and therefore it does not have an inverse function
in the sense that $f(x) = 2x$ does.

In complex numbers the exponential function $\exp(z) = e^z$ can produce the same output value for many different input values $z$, and therefore it cannot have a proper inverse function. It's useful to talk about the "function" $\ln$ in complex analysis, but you either have choose a "branch" of $\ln$ (meaning that $\ln$ can only give back values in a limited set, like the real $\arccos$ function)
or you turn $\ln$ into a "multivalued function"
(meaning that it gives back a lot of values at once every time you use it).

If you choose a branch of $\ln$ then $\ln(1)$ and $\ln\left(e^{2i\pi}\right)$
will always return the same value -- that is, you can choose a branch where both return $0$, or a branch where both return $2i\pi$, or a branch where both return some other integer multiple of $2i\pi$.
If you have chosen the branch on which $\ln(1)$ returns $0$ then
$\ln\left(e^{2i\pi}\right)$ also returns $0$, never $2i\pi.$

On the other hand, if you consider $\ln$ as a multifunction, then $\ln(1)$ returns all integer multiples of $2i\pi$, and so does $\ln\left(e^{2i\pi}\right)$.